# Android Studio "Bottom Navigation Activity" template leaves blank area on the top

Tags: android, android-jetpack, bottomnavigationview

I created new Android project by selecting “Bottom Navigation Activity”. No other change. Only modify
“fragment_notifications.xml” by adding background attribute to set background to black.

[image: Screenshot]

My question is:

- a) Why the fragment in black doesn't start right next to the blue
  title area, but leaving 1~2 cm blank on the top? What's the purpose
  of this area in the template? I don't think I'm so "lucky" to find
  bug obvious like this.
- b) How to eliminate the blank area.  I tried modifying
  "activity_main.xml" and "fragment_notifications.xml" adjusting
  width/height and constraint attributes but none of them works.

Thanks for your time in advance.

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1 and running the code on AVD Nexus 6 API 26, below is the source code of related files. All generated by Android Studio except the background of notification fragment.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

mobile_navigation.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.guo.butnavtest.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:name="com.guo.butnavtest.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:name="com.guo.butnavtest.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_notifications"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
```

fragment_notifications.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_notifications"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}

}
```

Comment: Look at your `fragment_notifications.xml`--the blank area you are talking about is the TextView `text_notifications`,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the fragment in black doesn't start right next to the blue title area

The reason: The `activity_main.xml` root layout (`ConstraintLayout`) has a `paddingTop` attribute that adds this top blank space which equals to the size of the `ActionBar`

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

The height of `ActionBar` size equals to **56dp**

```
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">56dp</dimen>
```

> How to eliminate the blank area.

Get rid of it.

UPDATE:

> a) What's the potential use of this padding, why the template leaves this padding? Never see an App with action bar under title bar

This could have opinion-based answers according to your design, but generally-speaking, you can think of it as a space for a subheader .. or maybe because the `ActionBar` can hold a limited width title..  [here](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#anatomy) you can find several design guidelines and uses of that.

> b)The constraint layout is the root node of this UI. But why the paddingTop isn't above the title area?

That is because the root layout size starts from the bottom of the **default** `ActionBar` which is set using App theme in `styles.xml`... You can verify that when you add a `View` at the top most part of the root layout, .. this view will be laid out directly below the `ActionBar` not behind it.

Comment: Thanks Zain. It resolved the issue perfectly. I still have two concerns: a) What's the potential use of this padding, why the template leaves this padding? Never see an App with action bar under title bar. b)The constraint layout is the root node of this UI. But why the paddingTop isn't above the title area?

Comment: @gg thanks for the comment .. please check updated answer .. and if this was helpful to you please accept the answer

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. Voted before but not accountable because my credit is not enough. Just accepted. It really helps a lot and saved much much time for me. Everything has been clarified clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing `textview` color

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_notifications"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
android:background="@color/black"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

If you want to get the area of `actionBar` than write

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```